# Connect to bluetooth device from another app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I have an app ("APP A") that connects to a Bluetooth device and discovers all of the services and characteristics required. I have another app ("APP B") that will attempt to call

```
 NSArray *connectedPeripheralArray = [centralManager retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:@[requiredUUID]];
```

and will retrieve the connected Bluetooth device (CBPeripheral) from the iOS system. Considering I previously discovered all the services and characteristics in "APP A", do I need to do it once again in "APP B" or can I just start using the services/characteristics as I wish?

P.S. The Bluetooth device is connected to iOS system the entire time after connects to "APP A".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to perform the full discovery. I assume your plan was to hard-code the various device identifiers into App B?  This will be unreliable as IDs can change over time.

You can rely on the underlying CoreBluetooth framework to cache information where appropriate.

Comment: I am building a health device and I wanted it to function similar to the Pebble smartWatch (if you are aware how it works). The pebble works by connecting the pebble device to the iOS system in the pebble app. Then, third party apps can reference the pebble device connected to the iOS system. I am trying to figure out how they made this happen. It makes no sense having to rediscover all the services again. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Pebble doesn't use Bluetooth 4.0 (Bluetooth LE) - It is an MFI partner -  so once the device is paired with a phone you can access it via the PebbleKit for iOS - https://developer.getpebble.com/2/mobile-app-guide/ios-guide.html/  The advantage of Bluetooth LE & CoreBluetooth is that it does not require the accessory to be MFI certified.  You simply discover your device using its service offerings. The process could work like this "Found new AcmeDevice - connect?" If user says yes then remember that device and next time you discover it, use it without prompting but you need to do it in each app

Comment: If you decide to go down the MFI route then you get access to different APIs that allow you to communicate with your device

Comment: Thank you Paul. This is the information I have been looking for. I will accept your answer. Just to be clear, my understanding is that if I am only developing using Bluetooth LE, I cannot go down the MFI route. is this correct?

Comment: I don't think you can't, it is just that you don't need to.  MFI imposes costs and effort but prior to BLE and CoreBluetooth it was the only way to get a peripheral to communicate with an iOS device.  There is nothing stopping you from providing a library that wraps around CoreBluetooth to make it easier to discover and communicate with your device - in fact if you want to build a developer ecosystem this is a good idea.  You can even offer a web/cloud service where people can register their devices and then your library could interrogate this to find a user's known devices

Comment: Correction- according to the MFI FAQ, if you only use BLE it isn't covered by MFI - https://mfi.apple.com/MFiWeb/getFAQ.action#1-1